Android Studio: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied) only for some files in same directory
I am creating an app that can convert objects to JSON so that they can be imported/viewed by the app on another device. I am getting this error only when viewing files created by the app on another device. I have access to the folder this txt is placed in as I am able to create and write files of the same type (txt with the JSON) within the folder and read the ones created by the app on that device.
I have the following in the manifest:
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        android:maxSdkVersion="32" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        android:maxSdkVersion="28" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS."/>

And android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" in the <application tag.
And the provider:
 <provider
            android:authorities="com.example.listtrial.fileprovider"
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths"
            />
        </provider>

And the following is how I read the txt files:
val docFolder = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS)
val exportsFold = File(docFolder, "ToeApp Exported Reports")

fun makeExportsFolder(){
    if (!exportsFold.exists()){
        exportsFold.mkdirs()
    }
    if (!toeAppDir.exists()){
        val makecheck = toeAppDir.mkdirs()
        Log.i("create File", "MakeCheck: $makecheck")
    }                   
}
fun getExpRep(uri: Uri, context: Context): ExportedRep?{
    val docFile = fromSingleUri(context, uri)
    val name = docFile?.name
    val path = uri.path?.split("/")
    Log.i("Path last seg" , "${path?.last()}")
    Log.i("file name" , "${name}")

    Log.i("Path check", exportsFold.path)

        if (name.isNotNull()){
            try {
                val filePath = File(exportsFold , name)
                Log.i("path check" , "Filepath: $filePath")
                val content = ByteArray(filePath.length().toInt())
                val stream = FileInputStream(filePath)
                stream.read(content)
                val repJSON = content.decodeToString()
                val expRep = Gson().fromJson(repJSON, ExportedRep::class.java)
                return expRep
            }
            catch(e: Exception){
                e.printStackTrace()
                Toast.makeText(context, "Select Exported Report", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                return null
            }

        }
        else return  null


As mentioned the app is able to read/write JSON of the ExportedRep in the same folder so I don't believe its a permission issue. Its only throwing the exception when attempting to read the file created by the app on another device. I'm testing between two device that both run Android 14.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Documents/ToeApp Exported Reports/Exported_Bruce Wayne_27_06_2024.txt: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
Thank you for the help!


Its only throwing the exception when attempting to read the file created by the app on another device

You only have rights to files in Documents that your app installation put there. If it was put there by the OS itself or another app -- including some previous installation of your app that was then uninstalled -- you have no rights to it.

is there any way to change this, and be able to read the string from the txt?

@SiddhantSamarth: Stop using files and switch to the Storage Access Framework (ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT / ActivityResultContracts.OpenDocument). You can use the resulting Uri with ContentResolver to get an InputStream on the contents of the user-selected document.
